# How do I check which of my installed modules is unsupported?

Tags: 7

When I go to `admin/modules`, I get this scary warning:

> The installed version of at least one of your modules or themes is no
>   longer supported. Upgrading or disabling is strongly recommended. See
>   the project homepage for more details. See the available updates page
>   for more information and to install your missing updates.

That sounds like something I'd like to fix!  So I click the "available updates" link, but that page tells me:

> All of your projects are up to date.

Hmmm.  I tried checking for updates with Drush (`drush up`) but Drush doesn't find any updates either.  **How can I find which modules installed in my site are unsupported?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As stated [here](https://www.drupal.org/node/961060), you need to go to admin/reports/updates rather than admin/reports/updates/update to see which module is having the problem.